# Bootstrap carousel v5.3 load image late when i click on next button ? Also how to resize the images in 500px * 500px

Tags: bootstrap-5

Below is my code for carousel

`<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide"> <div class="carousel-indicators"> <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button> <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button> <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button> </div> <div class="carousel-inner"> <div class="carousel-item active"> <img src="./images/abstract-autumn-beauty-multi-colored-leaf-vein-pattern-generated-by-ai_188544-9871.jpeg"  class="d-block w-100" alt="..."> <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block"> <h5>First slide label</h5> <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p> </div> </div> <div class="carousel-item"> <img src="./images/channel-2.jpeg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."> <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block"> <h5>Second slide label</h5> <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p> </div> </div> <div class="carousel-item"> <img src="./images/channel-1.jpeg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."> <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block"> <h5>Third slide label</h5> <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p> </div> </div> </div> <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev"> <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span> </button> <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next"> <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span> </button> </div>`